Word VBA Userform error 4218 "Types doesn't match"
New to this, first of all. It might just be obvious what the error is for you.
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim UnderskrivTitel As Range
Set UnderskrivTitel = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(UnderskrivTitel).Range
Dim UnderskrivTitel2 As Range
Set UnderskrivTitel2 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(UnderskrivTitel2).Range
UnderskrivTitel.Text = Me.TextBox7.Value
UnderskrivTitel2.Text = Me.TextBox7.Value
End Sub

This is a snip of my code. Essentially i want for a Userform to input some values in predetermined bookmarks in a Word document.
Debugger finds error af line 3 (Set UnderskrivTitel = Active...) Any ideas how to fix?
BONUS QUESTIONS:

I'm trying to have the Form open whenever the document is opened. I put this:

Sub AutoNew()
'Kør oplysningsskema når fil åbnes
UserForm1.Show
End Sub 

In the "thisDocument" part of the project, but it doesn't open automatically?
2. I want the UserForm to remember what input was put last time it was used- or gather when opening (whatever makes more sense). Any idea how this could be achieved?
Thanks in advance.
Tried the above, expecting it to work. Followed a video on youtube titled "Creating a userform in MS Word and using it to insert information into a bookmark", from the YT channel named: "LearningEngineer.com"

You're trying to set a variable UnderskrivTitel  to itself before it is anything which doesn't make any sense. First define the bookmark by it's actual name. You can find them by running this... For Each P In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks:     Debug.Print P.Name: Next P

You will learn more if you use the documentation. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.bookmarks.item for example, where you will learn the correct syntax for bookmark names. It is never a good idea to declare a variable with the same name as an object.
AutoNew will only work if you are using a template (*.dotm), not a document, as it executes when a new document is created. If you do use a template, and you should, then you should use Private Sub Document_New() instead (see the dropdowns at the top of the module).
To store previous input you could use document variables (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.variables), depending on why you want to use the previous input.
